# Can you set filename for "save as" on an image with a data url?

Tags: javascript

I have an image like this:

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,/9j...">`

When I right click on the image and choose 'save as', the save dialog comes up with "download.jpg" as the filename. I'd like to choose a different default filename. Adding a `download` tag on the img element doesn't seem to work. Is there some way to add a name to this?

I've seen this, but its about `<a>` tags: [Is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data: URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri/6943481#6943481)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control base64 images when user saves as](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549819/how-to-control-base64-images-when-user-saves-as)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034022/can-you-set-filename-for-save-as-on-an-image-with-a-data-url

Comment: @MaciejSikora now because of you I am in an infinite loop looking for some dupe...

Comment: I think it's a no-go... The closest I've got is this : http://plnkr.co/edit/biG96etB4CL2K3mtTMBW?p=preview Try from FF, in windowed mode, and then choose "View Image" in your context menu. Finally, look at the title of your page. *(yes all this just for that...)*

Comment: I think you're probably right Kaiido : /

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File object to image with correct file name instead of src="blob..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726789/file-object-to-image-with-correct-file-name-instead-of-src-blob)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try something like this using `caman.js`. Here is a example how it works. I know that it's not exactly what you want but take a look.
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/9j14Lt0p/)

You can also use the `<a>` tag to do that but it will download on click.

```
<a download="logo.png" href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">Download transparent png</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how to do that. But I can't control whether the user uses the right-click menu or not. Or.. I could, but disabling the context menu would be a worse option. Thanks tho

Comment: I don't think that are other options there for that

Comment: I use the download attribute of the <a> tag and this is about as good as it gets for now.